# C++ destructor crashing program

Tags: c++, destructor

I've spent a couple hours trying to figure out why my program is misbehaving and I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

[image: Result of running program]

The copy constructor and assignment operator are never called. This either means this isn't a rule of 3 problem, or I declared them incorrectly so the defaults are being called. The error mentions something about a valid heap pointer block, maybe I am using the 'new' keyword incorrectly?

Let me know if any more infmoratoin is required to help me out, thanks.

Main:

```
#include "Ring.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Ring<int> int_ring(3);
    int_ring.Add(1);
    int_ring.Add(2);
    int_ring.Add(3);
    int_ring.Add(4); // Will overwirte 1

    for (int i = 0; i < int_ring.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << int_ring.Get(i) << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ring template class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<class T>
class Ring
{
public:    
    Ring(int size);
    Ring(const Ring &other);
    ~Ring();    
    T* begin();
    T* end();
    Ring& operator=(const Ring rhs);
    void Add(T t);
    T Get(int i);
    int size();

private:
    int size_;
    T *t_;
    T *begin_;
    T *end_;

    void MoveIt() {
        t_++;
        if (t_ == end_) { t_ = begin_; }
    }

};

template<class T>
Ring<T>::Ring(int size) : size_(size), t_(new T[size_]), begin_(t_), end_(t_ + size_) {
}

template<class T>
Ring<T>::Ring(const Ring &other) : size_(other.size_), t_(new T[size_]), begin_(t_), end_(t_ + size_) {
    std::cout << "Copy\n";
}

template<class T>
T* Ring<T>::begin() { return begin_; }
template<class T>
T* Ring<T>::end() { return end_; }

template<class T>
Ring<T>& Ring<T>::operator=(const Ring<T> rhs) {
    std::cout << "=\n";
    std::swap(rhs);
    return *this;
}

template<class T>
void Ring<T>::Add(T t) {
    (*t_) = t;
    MoveIt();
}

template<class T>
T Ring<T>::Get(int i) {
    return begin_[i];
}

template<class T>
int Ring<T>::size() {
    return size_;
}

template<class T>
Ring<T>::~Ring() {
    std::cout << "delete\n";
    delete[] t_;
}
```

Comment: Hint: when `t_` gets advanced in `MoveIt()`, and subsequently the destructor runs, do you think that what the destructor `delete`[]s will be the same pointer that was originally returned by `new[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out, I was deleting 't_' which wasn't guaranteed to be pointing to the start of the allocated block. So I had to delete begin_ instead!

Comment: I know, but it takes 2 days